# Macos X 10.6 not refreshing Kerberos TGT key

Tags: macos, kerberos

I observed that MacOS X 10.6, if machine is added to an Active Directory and set to authenticate over LDAP to the Active Directory server requests a Kerberos TGT as expected at each user login.

However, this TGT has a lifetime on the Active Directory and should be refreshed before the time expires. Windows machines does this automatically about 1 hour before expiration, but the MACs in our network does not do this. So, when a MacOS reaches the end of the TGT lifetime, nothing happens and access to services is limited accordingly by the Active Directory server.

I am looking for a way to configure the MACs to do a TGT refresh without user intervention. Preferably the solution should be a setting somewhere or a cron job to be run, and if that's impossible what software should I install to automatically refresh the TGT?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I found out that `kinit -R` or `kinit -B` should refresh the TGT. When I run it, it seems to run OK, klist shows updated times ... but I see this error in the logs:
`(com.apple.Kerberos.renew.plist[9299]): Exited with exit code: 1` and of course nothing happens on the Active Directory server.